# Remove dash from a phone number

Tags: java, regex, phone-number

What regular expression using java could be used to filter out dashes '-' and open close round brackets from a string representing phone numbers...

so that (234) 887-9999 should give 2348879999
and similarly 234-887-9999 should give 2348879999.

Thanks,

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
phoneNumber.replaceAll("[\\s\\-()]", "");
```

The regular expression defines a character class consisting of any whitespace character (`\s`, which is escaped as `\\s` because we're passing in a String), a dash (escaped because a dash means something special in the context of character classes), and parentheses.

See [`String.replaceAll(String, String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

**EDIT**

Per [gunslinger47](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179984/gunslinger47):

```
phoneNumber.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

Replaces any non-digit with an empty string.

Comment: Might be best to just go for `"\\D"`.  It speaks the original intention more directly.  "Remove anything that's not a digit."

Comment: Both of the above works in my case... because I limit the user to enter only digits,, round brackets and dashes... Thanks a lot guys :)

Comment: Hi guys! What if i want to keep + in the string and remove all other characters?

Comment: As @ShajeelAfzal points out phone numbers can contain `+`.  The `phoneNumber.replaceAll("\\D", "")` suggestion is not conservative enough.

Answer (score 9):

```
    public static String getMeMyNumber(String number, String countryCode)
    {    
         String out = number.replaceAll("[^0-9\\+]", "")        //remove all the non numbers (brackets dashes spaces etc.) except the + signs
                        .replaceAll("(^[1-9].+)", countryCode+"$1")         //if the number is starting with no zero and +, its a local number. prepend cc
                        .replaceAll("(.)(\\++)(.)", "$1$3")         //if there are left out +'s in the middle by mistake, remove them
                        .replaceAll("(^0{2}|^\\+)(.+)", "$2")       //make 00XXX... numbers and +XXXXX.. numbers into XXXX...
                        .replaceAll("^0([1-9])", countryCode+"$1");         //make 0XXXXXXX numbers into CCXXXXXXXX numbers
         return out;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin version of working solution for me - (Extension Function)**

```
fun getMeMyNumber(number: String, countryCode: String): String? {
    return number.replace("[^0-9\\+]".toRegex(), "") //remove all the non numbers (brackets dashes spaces etc.) except the + signs
        .replace("(^[1-9].+)".toRegex(), "$countryCode$1") //if the number is starting with no zero and +, its a local number. prepend cc
        .replace("(.)(\\++)(.)".toRegex(), "$1$3") //if there are left out +'s in the middle by mistake, remove them
        .replace("(^0{2}|^\\+)(.+)".toRegex(), "$2") //make 00XXX... numbers and +XXXXX.. numbers into XXXX...
        .replace("^0([1-9])".toRegex(), "$countryCode$1") //make 0XXXXXXX numbers into CCXXXXXXXX numbers
}
```

Comment: Please notice that the question is about Java (even if Kotlin translation is not that hard) it does not apply to the context.

Comment: @Leonardo This answer is for the same question in Kotlin, as this will help others looking for exact solutions in kotlin but not java 