# Need regex for this phone number format

Tags: java, regex

I can't see to figure out this regular expression. I am using the following code to determine if the phone number is right

```
public static boolean verifyPhoneNum(String phone) {
         Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9*#+]+$");
         Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(phone.trim());
         return matcher.matches();
}
```

But it is not working as expected. The phone number can have any number of digits, #, -, +, white space, (, and )

I am making it as loose as possible. I just basically don't want letters in there (and preferrably any other special characters)

any help ? Thanks

Comment: Did you want a literal `*` or is that an attempt to capture repeating digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are special characters in there that need to be escaped (`*` and `+`):

```
public static boolean verifyPhoneNum(String phone) {
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9#\\+\\(\\)\\-]+$");
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(phone.trim());
     return matcher.matches();
}
```

That will allow any digit, `-`, `#`, `+`, `(` and `)`. Here is a [Regex101 link to the regex](https://regex101.com/r/oC3aU1/2) with an example (using the PCRE regex library).

Comment: When I use what you suggested, the ide says there are illigal escape characters and can not accept it! Any suggestion?

Comment: I missed the double escape java requires. The example has been updated.

Comment: Perfect it worked! I added the \\s to it to include the white spaces. Thanks for the helps. I have no idea why someone would downvote the question though

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to use `String.replaceAll(String, String)` instead of RegEx

Some of the responses for [Remove dash from a phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717421/remove-dash-from-a-phone-number) has some very interesting code that may help you.

See [String.replaceAll(String, String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).